# How to send rendered data using jquery ajax in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

how can I get the start and end time of the fullCalendar script? The value are picked by these lines of code

```
if (eventName != '') {
    //Render Event
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',{
        title: eventName,
        start: $('#getStart').val(),
        end: $('#getEnd').val(),
        allDay: true,
        className: tagColor

    }, true); //Stick the event

    $('#addNew-event form')[0].reset()
    $('#addNew-event').modal('hide');
}
```

How I can send them using jQuery ajax? I am very poor with js and jQuery. An explanation will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Not sure but: `$('#getStart').val()` for the start and `$('#getEnd').val()` for the end? This is where the script gets the values from (HTML elements)

Comment: Yes but I want to send this value to a php page to grab them and then store in mysql..

Comment: Well, there are many questions (and tutorials if you search on google) of how to make ajax requests.